# return minimum value from the field in meteor js

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I want to get the records which has minimum value of 1

I write like this in server side, It is showing

```
 the [object][object} has no such method min
```

return Videos.find({}).min({reportlen: 1});

Any alternatives???

Answer (score 0):

Use query selector [$gte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/)

```
// Matches documents where reportlen is greater or equal to 1
Videos.find({reportlen:{$gte:1}})
```